Reading a file relative to reusable workflow path
I am trying to access files at relative path to reusable workflow. For example I trying to create following directory structure so that when workflow is called {owner}/{repo}/{path}/{filename}@{ref}, I want to access the Dockerfile or main.tf in this {filename}.yaml. Right now these docker and terraform file lives in callee repo and I want them to move to reusable workflow since these files are common and never changes so instead of duplicating them into each new repo why not to move them to reusable workflow to avoid the duplication.
.github
├── CODEOWNERS
├── terraform
│   ├── main.tf
├── docker
│   ├── Dockerfile
...
└── workflows
    └── ci.yml

When workflow get triggered it act as if these files are local to the repos where it is called from and thats why this relative path is not working.

Did you try adding the filename as input to your reusable workflow so that it will now the origin and be able to create the absolute path based on this input dynamically?

A reusable workflow runs in the context of the calling repo, so any other files in the repository hosting the reusable workflow aren't accessible. You could copy them to the calling repo as part of the workflow itself, using a sparse checkout, for example.

@GuiFalourd, can you please share an example.

As Benjamin shared, the reusable workflow may not be the best solution here, or you would eventually have to clone a iac repository (with your terraform and docker files) all the time in it a job to manipulate them to perform the operation you want according to your context. An alternative could be to create a composite-action, only shared with your organization, that way you could have those files in the same repo than the action and access them using the ${{github.action_path}} variable, manipulating the filename as action input, that would be sent from the calling workflow.

The case described here is when a reusable workflow is hosted in its own repo.
Reusable workflows external to the repo that is consuming them are totally disconnected from the repositories where they reside. GitHub Actions simply pull down a tarball of the workflows directory without any subdirectories. There is no checkout of the external repo.
The reusable workflows are just like a shell script that we pull down using curl
curl https://host/script | bash

The script executes in the context of the local file system and has no concept of the remote server where it resides.
However, actions are different. They also reside in a remote repo. However, they bring down with them the file system of the remote repo. They are very similar in structure to a reusable workflow but their runtime model is different. They can have access to both file systems.
An action’s current directory contains files from its own repo.
This action can also access the file system of the invoking repo via environment variable GITHUB_WORKSPACE.
Therefore, if you want to host common files in a single repo, wrap them into a composite action. Composite actions are written in YAML just like workflows with some small syntactic differences. For example, actions do not define triggers and runners but they have steps and may have inputs and produce outputs.
Another difference between a reusable workflow and an action is that a reusable workflow represents a job and executes on a separate runner. An action represents a step in a job and executes on the same runner (or confined) as the steps before and after it. Therefore, an action can share runner(container) file system with other steps and actions, for example they all share a /tmp directory on the runner.
